# Revocation Information for this security certificate for this site is not available

Tags: java

I will randomly get a security alert window with a java logo that says the above, even if I'm not browsing the internet (I suspect java's auto-update or a number of other auto-updates for security software are the cause). After viewing the certificate, the only thing missing is the revocation information.

Is this safe to allow or should I select "No, do not proceed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *can* be an issue with the revocation (CRL) URL; perhaps the usertrust.com site is down. I get this occasionally too.

However, with the recent scares about cracking TLS communication, I choose to answer, "No, do not proceed." If the problem gets resolved on its own (the site is back up and running), then the next time Java attempts to update, you won't have an issue.

Unless you **really** need to update your Java for some security issue you're vulnerable to, just wait for the certificate to get worked out.

Note: This is, by no means, an official statement or definitive answer; simply a suggestion that errs on the side of caution.

Answer (score 1):

jucheck.exe is the application which triggers this.

I was getting these as well, and also found it confusing, then I remembered that I dial into work via VPN so need to switch my proxy settings on and off as required, so Windows is able to check the certificate validity.

Comment: Causality failed me here - this is not the solution - my apologies.